# How do you draw spectral lines from electron energy transitions in atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, particle-physics

I'm finding it difficult to visualize how to draw energy transitions such as n=4 to n=1, n=4 to n=2, n=4 to n=1 and n=3 to n=1 on a frequency diagram such as this:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the frequency of each transition [hint: or something easier that is proportional to it] and draw a vertical “[spectral line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_line)” at that frequency.

Comment: Do you mean like this ? so Line a frequency is based on n=4 to n=3, frequency= 1.599x10^14 Hz 
Line b based on n=4 to n=2 frequency =6.168x10^14Hz 
Line c based on n=3 to n=1 frequency= 2.924x10^15Hz 
Line d based on n=4 to n=1 frequency= 3.084x10^15Hz

Comment: I didn’t check your numbers, but calculating the actual frequency in Hz is certainly one way to do it. But if all you want is a diagram with lines spaced properly, rather than being able to have an actual frequency scale on the axis, think about my hint.

Comment: do you mean energy?

Comment: Last hint: Think about the way the transition frequencies depend on the two values of $n$. Any more than that is too close to doing a homework problem for you.